# Visual studio 2017 building to hololens error CS0246 "The type or namespace name 'UnityPlayer' Could not be found"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2017, hololens

I'm new with visual studio. All help are welcome.

I'm building a very basic scene, just a cube to display in hololens using unity3d. From unity there is no problem, followed tutorial step by step provided. When the sln file open in Visual Studio, this error pops out.

Using Unity 5.6.4f1 and Visual Studio 2017 15.3

I'm getting this error. "The type or namespace name 'UnityPlayer' Could not be found" and few more similar as in image attached below.

[Error list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ct9iP.png)

I've tried few things mentioned in similar problem that i've googled.

- i used x86 build, tried ARM build, Debug, Release all the same
- tried Unity 5.4.0, 5.5.0, 5.6.2, 5.6.3
- double triple check the build settings in unity
- Game development with Unity is installed
- checked windows 10 sdk (already installed 10.0.10240, 10.0.10586, 10.0.14393)
- tried visual studio 2015
- Downgrading visual studio to 2017v15.2 and 2017v15.0
- got latest net framework

Comment: It sounds like you may have something wrong with your build settings in unity can you share an image of your build settings?

Comment: Thanks for commenting, I got it work already with specific version Sergio pointed. apparently even the latest version of unity got problem. Thanks anyway. cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Unity 2017.1.0p5 and lasted version of VS2017.

Unity have an errors at oldest versions after the new updates of VS

Comment: 5.6.4f1 just live yesterday though, and I'm using latest VS2017 too. anyway let me try and i'll get back with the result. Thanks!